# jquery document scroll not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed navbar on my site that I'm trying to tie functions to once it reaches a certain point on the page. I've done this successfully three times before on three sites but can't for the life of me get it to work on this one. The function is wrapped in a window ready so I know the page is fully loaded -- completely stumped for two days... Here the code:

jQuery:

```
function startchange() {
$('#ajax-frame').imagesLoaded().done(function(instance) {
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var startchange = $('.startchange');
    var offset = startchange.offset();
    if (startchange.length) {
        $(document).on( 'scroll', function() {
            scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
                $('nav').addClass('active');
                console.log("startchange working");
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('active');
            };
        });
    }
});
};
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
height: 100% !important;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for any insight into this frustrating issue.

Comment: How do you fire `startchange` function ?  Are you sure you have `$('#ajax-frame').imagesLoaded().done` callback called ?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code so that we can run a minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're wrapping your code into a `startChange` function. Have you invoked it?

Comment: Yes it's wrapped in a window load: `$(window).load(function() {
   ***several other functions***
    setTimeout(function() {
        startchange();
        console.log("startchange loaded!");
    }, 500)
});`

Comment: the imagesLoaded plugin just makes sure all the images are loaded before firing the function but it still doesn't work without it... sorry to confuse the issue

Comment: I would add some breakpoints in your `startchange` function and check what's happening there in your console - how far you get into it, what scroll/offset values you get. Should be pretty straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick approach that will sove the issue is to remove: `overflow-x: hidden;` from your css. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/ce8me3qk/

But here is **what's happening**: you're setting `body` and `html` to height 100%, and one is overlapping the other (`html` tag is a block element too). You're setting both to height: 100% and actually what you're scrolling is `body`, and not `window/document`.

Proof: look at both scrollbar there when setting `overflow` to `scroll`: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/ce8me3qk/8/ Note that you're scrolling the **inner one**. So, if you change `$("document").on('scroll', function() {` to `$("body").on('scroll', function() {`, it will work too.

Or, just don't set `html` `height` to `100%`.

Comment: Thanks! Had that rule set on all the other working sites so it never occurred to me.

Comment: @pjldesign you're welcome. I edited with an explanation